# Hibernate - One To One IdentifierGenerationException

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, one-to-one

I have two entities like as below

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
@Audited
@AuditOverride(forClass = Auditable.class)
public class Foo extends Auditable implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    //other fields

    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @NotAudited
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "foo",
              fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
              cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
              orphanRemoval = true,
              optional = false)
    private FooDetail fooDetail;

}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo_detail")
public class FooDetail implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    //other fields

    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Foo foo;

}
```

I persist **Foo** like this

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.setId(1L);

FooDetail fooDetail = new FooDetail();
fooDetail.setId(1L);

foo.setFooDetail(fooDetail);
fooDetail.setFoo(foo);

fooRepository.save(i);
```

When **save** method is called **IdentifierGenerationException** is thrown. And it says "*attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [package.FooDetail.foo]*".

More interesting thing is when I use sequence generator on the parent entity(Foo) it works perfectly. But if I supply id manually throws this exception.

What am I doing wrong?

Environment

- Hibernate 5.3.10.Final
- Spring Boot 2.1.7.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

You could delete the `@JoinColumn` in `FooDetail` and it would work, but the id column would be named `foo_id`, you may not want that.

To fix that, all you need to do is change `@MapsId` to `@MapsId("id")` to let it know that's the id column now (since you are changing it with `@JoinColumn`).

Comment: Hi @Shadov, I tried this `@MapsId("id")` but this time schema validation(`hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate`) fails. It says 'foo_id' not found on the table.